# Hide options menu in xamarin android

Tags: android, menu, hide, optionmenu

I'm having a single activity in my android application which I'm developing with Xamarin.
There is an option menu in my application which is appearing in all the pages. I want the option menu to be hidden in my first page and then be visible in rest of the pages.

My code is like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        if (!UserPrefExist()) {

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.FirstPage);

            HandleSpinnerMethods ();
        } else {
            isFirstPage = false;
            DisplayMainPage ();
        }

    }
```

And then I'm having this method:

```
public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        IMenuItem menitm = menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.MyOption);
        if (isFirstPage) {
            menitm.SetEnabled (false);
            return false;
        } else {
            menitm.SetEnabled (true);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The options menu is getting hidden all right, but its getting hidden for all the pages, which is not desirable as I only want to hide the option menu in the first page.

Need help from you guys.

Thanks & Regards,
Anirban

Answer (score 0):

you should not directly enable/disable this on main page.as it is access locally obviously not affects other pages.You must set one `flag` in `if (isFirstPage) {` code instead of enabling/disabling and access that flag in rest of the pages to show menu or not.here you need to explicitly hide menu in these rest of the pages.

Comment: OK. Whats happening is that in the first run the options menu is becoming invisible for all the pages but on the second run it is visible to all the pages since as per my application logic it is skipping the first page. Now, this is also not desirable. I like to make my options menu available to all the pages except for the first page even in the first run.

Comment: then in this case no need to maintain flags of First Run,as case is same for every run.just disable it for first screen and enable it for rest every time.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if it is useful to you.

Comment: Hi @Vits,

Actually, the scenario is: my application would check whether the user preference has already been provided: If it has been provided, the application would skip the first screen. So, on subsequent run the first page would not load. But, on the first run, the first page would load and when the user provides the preference, the application would load the second page and so on.

Comment: But, on the first run, since the user has not provided the preference yet, the application would load the first screen and I have been able to disable the options menu, but then when the second screen loads, in the first run, the options menu is still invisible.

Comment: then you need to check for preference before OnCreate of First screen.On that basis you can store some flag to local app storage,then on next launch just check that flag.just initialize flag with some default value.